# How to input URL type image into imageviewer

Tags: java, image, swing, url, imageicon

This is my code:

```
Image img1 = new ImageIcon("http://www.funchap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Cute-Dog-         Wallpapers.jpg").getImage();"
setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3,5,5));
add(new ImageViewer(img1));
```

I got an error that cant put url typed image into the ImageIcon how to fix it. thank you.

Comment: What is an "ImageViewer"? You ask your question as if this is a standard core Java class that we should know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a URL object first; you can't just pass in a String. For instance:

```
String imagePath = "http://....";
URL url = new URL(imagePath);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```